excel range lookup where the columns are not adjacent
I can use vlookup to return the value from column C for the input value, but how do I return the value from column D instead of column C?
e.g.
data setup
in this example I want to return 0.2 instead of B
I tried =VLOOKUP(F7,A2:C6,4,TRUE) and =VLOOKUP(F7,A2:D6,4,TRUE) but neither of those worked
